# imagecache of atrium in Drupal

Tags: drupal

imagecache of atrium in Drupal is not shown in www.example.com/atrium/admin/build/imagecache.
i want to enable the imagecache in drupal atrium. but as the instruction of drupal.org, when i go to the www.example.com/atrium/admin/build/imagecache, i cant found the option like imagecache there. but i found that something write like that

You will need to make sure the Imagecache UI module is enabled in order to build this.

So as the instruction where imagecache UI module can be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the imagecache ui module at the modules page, that should be at www.example.com/atrium/admin/build/modules